# Why is $R(i)=r(i)+\mathbb N_0 d(i)$?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

> Let $R(i):=\{k\in\mathbb N:p_{k}(i|i)>0\}$ then the period is $d(i)=\gcd R(i)$. Denote also $r(i)$ be the minimum of $R(i)$. Why is it then that $R(i)=r(i)+\mathbb N_0 d(i)$ ?

It is clear that for a chain $p_{d(i)}(i|i)>0$ does not necessarily hold, for example if $R(i)=\{4,8,10,\dots\}$ (gcd is $2$ but it is not in the set). Now, what forces $6$ to be also in $R(i)$ ?

Notations: $p_k(i|i)=\Pr(X_k=i|X_0=i)$ and $d(i)$ is the period of the state $i$.

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough information. What are you talking about? I see the tag Markov Chains? Wha tis $p_k$?

Comment: I guess $p_k(x\vert y)$ is supposed to be something like $\mathbb{P}[X_k = y \vert X_0 = x]$. But I don't immediately recognize what $d$ is supposed to be. Is $d$ the "period"?

Comment: And it looks like it should be $\mathbb{N}_0$ instead of $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get the statement? It looks wrong to me. A counter-example follows.

Consider a chain that looks like an "$\infty$"-symbol and consists of two linked cycles of length 1000 and 1001. Let $i$ be the node that links the two cycles. Whenever the chain is at the node $i$, it goes to the left cycle or the right cycle with probability $1/2$, and then has to go around the entire cycle until it reaches $i$ again. It holds: $R(i) = \{1000, 1001, 2000, 2001, 2002, 3000, 3001, 3002, 3003, ...\}$. The period $d(i)$ is then clearly $1$. However, *nothing* forces $1500$ to be in the set $R(i)$, so $R(i) \neq 1000 + \mathbb{N}_0$.

Determining the right offset $r$ such that $R(i) = \{e_1, \dots, e_n\} \cup (r + d(i) \mathbb{N}_0)$, where $e_1, \dots, e_n$ are finitely many exceptions from the simple rule, is not trivial: it's related to the [Coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem), and is NP-hard.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/6trpwsr43/ To prove is statement $5)$ the inequality in the third last line is also wrong it should be $p_{k+λ}(j|j)≥\epsilon p_k(i|i)$

Comment: I see only a single page from some manuscript about probability theory that has at least 106 pages. There are thousands of books and manuscripts that would fit the description. Have you looked into the list of errata?

Comment: Yes you're right I found the errata, it seems that he replaced almost half of the page http://s15.postimg.org/lqkmazraj/errata.png the book is ''Basic Stochastic Processes''
by Zdzislaw Brzezniak and Tomasz Zastawniak by the way

Comment: Well, errare humanum and so on... Do you want to modify your original question, or did I answer all your questions with regard to this paragraph?